# Using realloc in recursion

Tags: c, memory-leaks, recursion, realloc

Can I do this in C? Valgrind complains that realloc produces an invalid free?

```
int main(){
    void* mem;
    // Do stuff
    recurfunc(123, mem);
    // Do stuff
    if(mem)
        free(mem);
    return 0;
}

void recurfunc(int x, void* mem){
     .....
     // Do stuff
     mem = realloc(mem, newsize);
     // Do stuff
     recurfunc(x, mem);
     .....
}
```

Comment: if(mem) isn't needed: free given a NULL pointer is a no-op.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does indeed complain, because the `void *` you're passing in as `mem` is a *copy* of the pointer. Changes to the pointer within the function will *not* be reflected back to `main`.

If you want to change `mem` in the function *and* have it reflected back, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

The following code illustrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void fn (void *p1, void **p2) {
    p1 = realloc(p1, 200);
    *p2 = realloc (*p2, 200);
    printf ("    In call: %p %p\n", p1, *p2);
}

int main (void) {
    void *x1 = malloc (100);
    void *x2 = malloc (100);
    printf ("Before call: %p %p\n", x1, x2);
    fn (x1, &x2);
    printf (" After call: %p %p\n", x1, x2);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Before call: 0x896f008 0x896f070
    In call: 0x896f0d8 0x896f1a8
 After call: 0x896f008 0x896f1a8
                    ^
                    +--- Note this bit.
```

and you can see that the first value is *retained* in `main` despite it being changed within the function.

Comment: Do not forget to check the result of `realloc` (it can return `NULL`). And you should also initialize `mem` to `NULL` in `main` (otherwise the program will crash almost immediately because you're passing an unitialized pointer to `realloc`).

Comment: Your first realloc reallocates from invalid memory.

Comment: Bods, I thought you may be talking about something I fixed in the early edits (since it's not in the edit history). Currently, at no stage is either realloc using an invalid pointer.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, thanks for the explanation. However it is not complaining at the free line in main. It is complaining about the realloc function in the recursive function...

Comment: That's correct, @Jethro, it's the reallocation which is the problem. You reallocate the block and put the new address into the local (in `recurfunc`) copy of `mem` then effectively throw that address away and revert to the old freed block when you return to `main` (or previous levels of `recurfunc`).

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot paxdiablo. Very clear and concise explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Any code that uses

```
x = realloc(x, size);
```

is potentially leaking unless also some other variable holds the current value of `x`.

The reason is that if reallocation fails the return value is `NULL` so the current "unresized" memory block is lost.

In your code moreover you are

1. passing an uninitialized pointer to the function
2. any computation done in the function will not alter the variable seen by `main`
3. freeing that uninitialized pointer once the recursive function returns

So no matter what happens in your code is "undefined behaviour".